# Column mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min not working

Tags: dart, flutter

So I'm displaying some cards in a horizontal listview,problem is, I cant control card's height.

I've already try with mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min but nothing happens.

```
list.add(Card(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("Some text"),
      ],
    ),
  ));
```

This is what im getting.

[image]

Comment: the problem is with the parent of the ListView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a height constraint to your `ListView` widget , like this:

```
SizedBox(
      height: 100.0,
      child: ListView.builder(
      ...
```

Also you can center your items:

```
        Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 100.0,
            child: ListView.builder(
            ...
```

Comment: Thanks! this solved my problem, small question, how do you align bottom instead of center?

Comment: Try using Align (with alignment = Alignment.bottomCenter) instead of Center

Answer (score -1):

Try ListView

```
return ListView(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  // background is red
  children: [
     ...
  ]
)
```